# Can you map/reduce a String into an Int?

Tags: kotlin

I was solving a problem on codeforces in which I had to sum up the digits of a big number (it can have up to 100k digits) and I'd have to repeat that process until there is only one digit left and count the number of times I did that and I came up with a working solution, however I'd like to know if some things could have been done in a more "Kotlin-ish like way", so given:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(transform(readLine()!!))
}

fun transform(n: String): Int {
    var count = 0
    var sum : Int
    var s = n
    while(s.length > 1) {
        sum = (0 until s.length).sumBy { s[it].toInt() - '0'.toInt() }
        s = sum.toString()
        count++
    }
    return count
}
```

1. `sum = (0 until s.length).sumBy { s[it].toInt() - '0'.toInt() }` is there a way to I guess map the sum of digits in the string to the sum variable, or in general a better approach than the one I used?
2. When converting a Char to an Int it converts it to the ASCII value so I had to add "-'0'.toInt()" is there a faster way (not that it's too much to write, asking out of curiosity)?
3. How to make the String n mutable without creating a new String s and manipulating it? Or is that the desired (and only) way?

P.S. I'm a beginner with Kotlin.

Comment: `s.map { "$it".toInt() }.sum()` returns the sum of the digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When converting a Char to an Int it converts it to the ASCII value so I had to add "-'0'.toInt()" is there a faster way (not that it's too much to write, asking out of curiosity)?

You can simply write `s[it] - '0'`, because subtracting Chars in Kotlin already gives you an Int:

```
public class Char ... {
    ...
    /** Subtracts the other Char value from this value resulting an Int. */
    public operator fun minus(other: Char): Int
    ...
}
```

But why are looping over the indexes when you could loop over the Chars directly?

```
sum = s.sumBy { it - '0' }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a functional (and recursive) style to solve it:

```
private fun sum(num: String, count: Int) : Int {
    return num
        //digit to int
        .map { "$it".toInt() } 
        //sum digits
        .sum()
        //sum to string
        .toString() 
        //if sum's length is more than one, do it again with incremented count. Otherwise, return the current count
        .let { if (it.length > 1) sum(it, count + 1) else count } 
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
val number = "2937649827364918308623946..." //and so on
val count = sum(number, 0)
```

Hope it helps!